# How does one write system-level tools such as debuggers and profilers by reflection?

Tags: reflection, debugging

> Reflection makes it easy to write
>   system-level tools such as debuggers
>   and profilers.

I know that C debuggers uses the `ptrace` syscall to implement themselves.

How can one implement a debugger by reflection?

**UPDATE**

What's the principle to implement a debugger with reflection?

Comment: Where is that quote from?  I'm not sure it makes it easy at all... :)

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham ,from the <advance perl programing> . I have no idea how one can implement a debugger by reflection

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific use case for writing your own java debugger?

Java comes with a debugger, jdb. There are plenty of debugger interfaces out there that are very powerful that can be run locally and remotely. In a development environment, most IDEs (eclipse, intelliJ, NetBeans, ...etc) have built-in debugger interfaces that provide excellent functionality and use jdb.

Comment: The OP didn't mention Java specifically (although I think your assumption is correct).  Their question could be in relation to .Net, or many other languages.

Comment: Good Point- no mention of Java!

Comment: @Moe Matar,you didn't answer the question regarding principle.